# is a water inlet valve water resistive by design?

Tags: safety, solenoid-valve, waterproof

I cleaned a leaky washing machine water inlet valve with wd-40, pressurized water, pressrized air, drain opener(caustic soda+ sodium chloride), vinegar and alcohol and gave it a massage gun session using all frequencies after the water.
Should I dry it before reinstalling it or is it safe to dry it superficially and reinstall it right away?
I was thinking about putting it in the fridge then let it under the sun for a while.

C-136/14-14-10
334913600 5220FR125LE
220/240V 50/60Hz

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the fridge part for?

Comment: @Transistor Well, Cold air holds much less moisture than warm air. By removing heat from the system (the atmosphere in the fridge) the cooling mechanism also removes water vapour. But when air becomes drier liquid water can evaporate more easily, so wet things like meat cheese, and wet valves will dry out faster or so I thought . check this out https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425520/226188

Comment: Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think the actual problem is already solved and the valve is not leaking anymore after testing it externally without power. The question is about whether I should take extra measures to dry water that may have leaked into the solenoid system above the water way during the messy cleaning process with bursting water which made the entire device wet. This valve valve should always stay closed until its powered and only then it should let the water in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solenoid of the valve will be partially resistive but will also be inductive as it is a coil. This is pretty much irrelevant to your problem.

The solenoid coil is potted and, provided the potting is not cracked, is completely waterproof apart from the 1/4" spade terminals. If the outside is dry and the terminals are dry then it's ready for action.

---

Sorry, I've re-read your question by "water resistive" you meant resistant to water. I took it to mean electrical resistance for some reason.

Comment: yes the two solenoids appear to be potted, I will install it and see. Thank you

Comment: I will install it tomorrow because I did something I didn't mention, I massaged it with a massage gun using all frequencies while it was wet hoping that it will release some internal stuck parts and the vibration may have leaked some water inside . If it doesn't work tomorrow I will smear it with wd-40 and give a massage gun session then I will order a new part if it doesn't work.